# tkinter python text-align left

Tags: python, tkinter

In python.tkinter, I want to make text in labels to align left.
Also, I want to use pack so, I tried "pack" and "anchor". But it doens't work.
In the code,
all_img_onePx is one_pixel Image.
I used it to size label in pixel.

Here is my code :

```
self.categoryLabel = tk.Label(self.innerFrame, text="category", image=self.css.all_img_onePx, compound="center", width=self.css.deviceInfo_categoryBox_width, heightht=self.css.deviceInfo_titleLabel_height)
self.categoryLabel.pack(side="left", anchor="nw")
self.valueLabel = tk.Label(self.innerFrame, text="value", image=self.css.all_img_onePx, compound="left",  width=self.css.deviceInfo_valueBox_width, height=self.css.deviceInfo_titleLabel_height)
self.valueLabel.pack(side="left", anchor="nw")
```

Comment: `anchor="nw"` should be used in `tk.Label(...)` instead.

Comment: thx a lot!. I remember your id and a lot of helps of you. Thx a lot acw1668!!